# How can I get the kernel Matrix values of the CNN?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network

I am new to machine learning. I am working with a [Neural Network](https://github.com/Ugness/PiCANet-Implementation) that implements the U-Net.
The thing which I understand is when a convolutional layer is created:

```
createsconv2d = nn.Conv2d(in_channels, v, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
```

let the `in_channel = 3` and `out_channel = 64` then,
for `kernel_size = 3` it computes with a 3*3 Kernel.

But my question is what are the values of this kernel? How it gets the values?

Comment: Here's a search to get you started: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bbackpropagation%5d%20how%20cnn%20answers%3a1%20score%3a1

Answer (score 1):

Those are the *learnable* parameters which are learnt through the usual [back-propagation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation) algorithm. They can be accessed before and after the learning phase via `nn.weight` as described in the PyTorch [manual](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html).